# Is content in option tags indexed?

Tags: seo, html, forms

Is data inside an `<option>` tag indexed?

For example, would the following `option` tag allow "Volvo", "Saab", "Opel" and "Audi" to be indexed by a crawler?

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Will search engines put any weight on data in an `option` form element?

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by inside a tag? What type of tag? Do you mean options such as radio groups or check boxes and their labels? If you mean the text displayed next to these options in forms and such the answer is yes they'll be indexed. All text which you can see in your browser along with some other attributes such as `alt` in image tags etc are also taken into consideration when indexing a page.

Comment: The OP is referring to the content inside `option` elements, but the question is badly formatted and needs 1 more person to approve the edit. ;)

Comment: I would imagine since the text is technically rendered on the page it's counted in some way towards the pages relevancy. An automobile  site using a select or multiselect menu with all auto manufacturers would be  helpful to Google. It's not really hidden text